# Prove that $f$ is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f$ be a real valued application on a measurable set $(X,A)$ show that if the set $\{{x \in X : f(x) > r}\}$ is measurable for every $r \in \mathbb Q$, then $f$ is measurable

Comment: Try to see that intervals with boundary points in $\mathbf{Q}$  generate the Borel $\sigma$-field of $\mathbf{R}$

Comment: since $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ we have that any open interval of $\mathbb R$ can be written in the form of unions of interval with boundary points in $\mathbb Q$ is it correct ?

Comment: Yeah...correct . Did you get the solution now?

Comment: I think I have the idea; since the Borel sigma field of $\mathbb R$ is generated by these sets, and since they are measurable, the function is measurable... something like that.

If someone can put it in a more formal way it would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments, first observe that intervals with boundary points in $\mathbf{Q}$ generate the Borel $\sigma$-field of $\mathbf{R}$. Now use an easy but very useful lemma:

$f:(X,\mathcal{A})\rightarrow (Y,\mathcal{B})$ a function. If $\mathcal{C}$ is a generating set of $\mathcal{B}$ , then $f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal{C}))=\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal{C}))$

I think one can prove this using "Good Set Principle".  Now we need to show $f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal{C}))\subset \mathcal{A} \Leftrightarrow \sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal{C}))\subset \mathcal{A} $ . The question says, $f^{-1}(\mathcal{C})\subset \mathcal{A} $, as $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-field, this says, $\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal{C}))\subset \mathcal{A} $. So, we are done.